# Laptop suddenly went black and powered off

Tags: laptop, power, hardware-failure

I have a Dell Inspiron 1720. I have had no problems with this laptop, until one day I'm working on my laptop and out of nowhere the screen turns black and the only thing on is the power light but after a minute it turns itself off.

So not knowing what happens I turn it back on, should I say I press the power button to turn it back on and the only thing that happens is the power button will blink the screen stays black and after a minute it powers itself back off and that is all it will do now.

If someone could tell me what happened or how I might be able to fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The battery probably isn't holding its charge.

If your power supply was plugged in to charge the battery, then there could be a connection problem (the power connectors do wear out frequently on laptops and are a problem for some people -- they'll seem like they're working yet the battery isn't actually getting re-charged).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got failed hardware, but one thing to try would be to disconnect the battery and the power cord, then hold the power button for about a minute (this part it just something I've heard for this situation; it's easy enough to do, so I've never put the effort into figuring out whether it could possibly help or if it's just voodoo someone invented).

Then, reconnect the power supply and see if the laptop will power on. If not, then it seems that the laptop hardware is the culprit. The easiest solution would be to call Dell support or bring it to a computer repair shop.